# Cannot write into a file in java as it is printing using System.out.println

Tags: java, file, bufferedwriter

```
File output=new File("C:\\\\MDU-1617-CSJ0098\\\\web\\\\products.txt");
BufferedWriter writer1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output));               
while(q_set2.next()) {
    String s = String.valueOf(q_set2.getInt(1));
    System.out.print(s);
    writer1.write(s);
    writer1.newLine();
}
```

and the ouput is 
run:
123456BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

But in file there is no data

Comment: First catch IOException and also use path like this "C:\MDU-1617-CSJ0098\web\products.txt".

Comment: Did you close the `BufferedWriter`?

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write) is what the `write` method does:

> Ordinarily this method stores characters from the given array into
>   this stream's buffer, flushing the buffer to the underlying stream as
>   needed.

So, it writes to `buffer` rather than directly writing to file. To make the buffer `flush`, you need to either call `flush` or `close` method, e.g.:

```
File output = new File("C:\\\\MDU-1617-CSJ0098\\\\web\\\\products.txt");
BufferedWriter writer1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output));
while (q_set2.next()) {
    String s = String.valueOf(q_set2.getInt(1));
    System.out.print(s);
    writer1.write(s);
    writer1.newLine();
}
writer1.close();
```

`close()` calls `flush()` internally and hence, you don't need to call `flush()` explicitly in this case (here's the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close())).

Answer (score 0):

When you call `writer1.write(s)`, you're not actually printing anything in your file, you're gathering data into memory. Once you've gathered all the data, you can write all of it at once into your file by calling `flush()`.

This is because writing into a file is a costly operation, so `BufferedWriter` is designed in such a way that that it facilitates writing all data at once instead of writing it in chunks.

That's why you need to *flush the stream.*

[Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush())

> *public void flush() throws IOException*
>
> Flushes the stream.

Now eiter you can...

1. Call `flush()` method or
2. close the stream. This will automatically call `flush()` method.

.

```
File output=new File("C:\\\\MDU-1617-CSJ0098\\\\web\\\\products.txt");
         BufferedWriter writer1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output));               

while(q_set2.next())  {
    String s=String.valueOf(q_set2.getInt(1));
    System.out.print(s);
    writer1.write(s);
    writer1.newLine();
}

writer1.flush(); // or writer1.close();
```